# Welche anderen Wörter der lateinischen U-Deklination werden im Deutschen verwendet?

Tags: loanword, latin

Um auf die Frage zum Plural von Status zu antworten, hätte ich gerne ähnliche andere Beispiel durchgedacht, mir sind aber keine eingefallen, daher meine Frage:

> **Welche anderen Wörter der lateinischen U-Deklination werden im Deutschen verwendet?**

Comment: http://faql.de/numerus.html#status <-- da werden als "andere Wörter auf us mit kompliziertem Plural" Abakus, Bonus und Rebus genannt. Außer (fälschlicherweise) Abakus wird aber bei keinem die u-Deklination angewandt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Als Beispiele fallen mir spontan noch

- Kasus und
- Sinus
- Passus
- Lapsus
- Usus (aber im Deutschen nur im Singular verwendet)
- Sexus
- Campus

ein. [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/InflectionRules/Controller?entryClass=Cat%20N&inflectionClass=-/fremder%20PL&resultId=531ef7&pageSize=50&pageNo=1) hat eine recht ausgiebige Liste, leider lassen sich jedoch nicht nur die Wörter herausfiltern, die hier gefragt sind. Durch einen Klick auf [Flexion](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=abusus&features=(Cat%20N)(Gender%20M)) kann man herausfinden, dass [Abusus](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abusus) auch zu den Wörtern der u-Deklination gehört. Leider nimmt danach die Trefferquote bei mir zumindest drastisch ab. Die Mehrzahl der Wörter auf -us gehören wohl zur o-Deklination.

Comment: Campus ist nicht u-Deklination, sondern o-Deklination.

Comment: Der wohl häufigsten verwendete Begriff aus der u-Deklination ist _Jesus Christus_, wo man zumindest im Genitiv noch den _Leib Jesu Christi_ kennt.

Comment: *Christus* ist o-Deklination, dagegen ist *Jesus* ein komplizierter Fall, da hier anscheinend die Flexion aus dem Griechischen übernommen wurde, weswegen der Genitiv meist *Jesu* ist und nicht *Jesus*, wie es in der lateinischen u-Deklination eigentlich sein sollte.